# Kendo declarative grid and making filterable.extra 'false'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a declarative grid inside a template and I'd like to allow the columns to be filterable, but with **filterable.extra** set to '**false**'. Is this possible?

[Here's a JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/inikib/1/edit)

I've tried every variation of data-filterable-extra="true" / data-filterableextra="true" / data-filterableExtra="true" / etc...

And ideally, I'd only have the input box and assume that the search method is 'contains'.

*Note that this lives within a template, and that I need to loop through an array to get the values, so my implementation actually [looks more like this](http://jsbin.com/utapot/1/edit).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use: `data-filterable="{ extra: false}"`. So the declarative definition for the `table` would be:

```
<table data-role="grid" data-sortable="true" data-filterable="{extra : false}" data-scrollable="false">
    ...
</table>
```

See your example modified here  http://jsbin.com/inikib/4/edit

Comment: Regarding the second part (loop) you actually don't need since being a grid Kendo UI will do it for you. If you need help please post it a question and I will be glad to help you.